# Module parse failed when using react component library in windows

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, create-react-app

I am struggling with using a react component library in my react application, and I am unsure on where to start looking for a solution. Googling didn't help my particular case.

So, I have a react application created with CRA (Yes, I know it is deprecated). My application has a dependency on a component library that is created inhouse. I am running on Windows.

Just to reproduce the issue I have this very simple app:

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { Hero } from "my-library/dist/Hero";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
      <Hero />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run this with npm run start I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/my-library/dist/Hero/index.tsx 6:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import "../cdn.scss";
| 
> export type HeroBreadcrumbProps = {
|   value?: string;
|   href?: string;
```

The index.tsx file in the library looks like this (simplified for abbreviation)

```
import React from "react";
import { Color, HeaderTag } from "../shared";

import "../cdn.scss";

export type HeroBreadcrumbProps = {
  value?: string;
  href?: string;
};

export type HeroProps = {
  tag?: HeaderTag;
  title?: string;
  text?: string;
  image?: string;
  alt?: string;
  index?: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  breadcrumbs?: Array<HeroBreadcrumbProps>;
  background?: Color;
  className?: string;
};

export const Hero = React.forwardRef(
  ({
    tag = "h1",
    title,
    text = "",
    image,
    alt = "",
    index = false,
    children,
    breadcrumbs = [],
    background = "teal-10",
    className = ""
  }: HeroProps) => {
    const Tag = tag;

    return (
      <section
        content here
      </section>
    );
  }
);
```

In IntelliJ the index.tsx can be expanded to show index.d.ts and index.d.ts.map if that matters.

What is strange is that I am the only one having problems. The other team members (who are on macOS) have no issues. I tried setting up the project on another windows machine as well which had no developer tools installed previously (node, git, etc), and I run into the same problem.

Can someone please assist? Many thanks!